# Django ORM annotate query with length of JSONField array contents

Tags: python, django

I have a basic Model with a JSONField that defaults to a list:

```
class Map(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        editable=False,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
    locations = models.JSONField(
        default=list, blank=True, encoder=serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder
    )
```

In my admin list view I'd like a column displaying the length of `locations`. That is, `annotate` the queryset to do the equivalent of `len(obj.locations)` but I haven't found any examples of this scenario.

I know I could write an accessor for the admin class that does `len(obj.locations)` to add the column/values but I'd also like to sort/order by this field's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31973?cversion=0&cnum_hist=22#comment:21):

```
Map.objects.annotate(num_locations=Func('locations', function='jsonb_array_length', output_field=IntegerField()))
```